# Aggregate and Sort Documents based on array element date time and field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have the following schema:

```
User:{
     verified:boolean,
     history:[{
          type:string,
          dateTime:datetime
     }]
}
```

I need to aggregate and sort the data based on the history.type and history.datetime. For example, I have 100 documents. Half of it have history.type="Testing" and each of the history have its own datetime. 
I need to match the history type and sort the datetime using mongoose nodejs.

Here is what I did but didn't work as expected:

```
let user = await User.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    "nameVerified":true,
                    'history.type' : 'NAME_VERIFIED'
                }
            },
            {$unwind: '$history'}, 
        {
            $match: {
                'history.type' : 'NAME_VERIFIED'
            }
        },  
        {
            $group : {
                _id :'$_id'
            }
          },
        {
            $sort: 
            {
                'history.dateTime': -1
            }
        }]);
```

Sample Data:

```
{_id:1,verified:false,history:[...]}
{_id:2,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-23},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-25}]}
{_id:3,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-24},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
{_id:4,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-21},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
{_id:5,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-22},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
```

Expected results:

```
{_id:3,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-24},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
{_id:2,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-23},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-25}]}
{_id:5,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-22},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
{_id:4,verified:true,history:[{type:"NAME_VERIFIED",dateTime:2018-10-21},{type:"TEST",dateTime:2018-10-21}]}
```

Anyone can suggest a solution?

Comment: In your model history property is an array and you are fetching it as an object take care of it.

Comment: Ya. I am fetching it as an object. I match it with the NAME_VERIFIED and sort the history datetime and as well. But still cannot.

Comment: what is the expected result in json?

Comment: @Astro Please check the updated question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution as follow:

```
User.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                "nameVerified":true,
                "history.type": 'NAME_VERIFIED',
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$history'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "nameVerified":true,
                "history.type": 'NAME_VERIFIED',
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                'history.dateTime': -1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                'history': {
                    '$push': '$history'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                'history.dateTime': -1
            }
        },
        {
            $skip: skipNo
        },
        {
            $limit: limitNo
        }
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return array of documents with matching `history.type` and sorted by `history.dateTime`.

```
User.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      "history.type": 'NAME_VERIFIED',
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$history'
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "history.type": 'NAME_VERIFIED',
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'history.dateTime': -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      '_id': {
        '_id': '$_id',
        'verified': '$verified'
      },
      'history': {
        '$push': '$history'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      '_id': '$_id._id',
      'verified': '$_id.verified',
      'history': 1
    }
  }
])
```

If anything should be changed in criteria, please let me know, I will try to reshape the query.

Comment: It still cannot. Although the results return is match the history.type but it is not sorted by history.datetime.